No hot water to washing machine
We have a 1960s home that had a laundry room built off the side of it. The washing machine is not getting any hot water. The kitchen, which is right beside it has hot water in the bathroom has hot water. There is a tankless hot water heater on the back side of the house near the bathroom.

Has it alwayd been this way or is this a recent problem?

Is the water flowing into the washer but just not hot? Or is there no water?

Here are some steps you can do to troubleshoot the hot water supply problem. First, take a look at the hoses to make sure the hot water hose isn't kinked or the valve is turned off.
Then, if you don't find any problems, turn off the water (both hot and cold) to the washer and remove the hot water hose to examine the water inlet on the washer. In many cases debris or foreign materials can accumulate in a filtering screen where the water goes in this can be especially true of the hot water supply. Some washing machine water hoses also have filtering screens installed where the hoses screw on to the wall fittings.
Now, if you don't find any debris in the supply hose, stick the hot water supply hose in a nearby sink, bucket, or other container and turn the hot water supply valve on. If water comes out, you know the problem is not "in the wall" and the issue is most likely inside your washer. If you don't get any hot water, the problem is somewhere between your water heater and the washer inlet. Trace the lines back to the water heater and look for trouble.
If you got water out of the hot water supply hose, you might try swapping the hot and cold water supply lines to the washer and run a "cold only" cycle which will be utilizing hot water since you swapped the hoses. If this works it further suggests that the washer's inlet valve or control system is not working correctly. For "completeness" try a "hot only" cycle and expect it to not supply cold water. This will confirm what we now suspect at this point.
At this point, you're looking at replacing the inlet valve on the washer. This is usually a fairly inexpensive and simple procedure, and there are tons of how-to videos available on sites like YouTube. You should search for videos bases on the make and model of your washing machine.

Plus one for the hose filters needing cleaning.
